# "sh: Error: Can't open display" when I try to start a program from python

Tags: python, linux, raspbian, systemd

I have this really strange problem, basically I want to start `xpdf` (or Libreoffice) from my `Python` script, that is started by a systemd-service. When I start the script from terminal everything is working fine, but when I plug in my USB device that start the Service, I'll get this Error in my syslog:

```
sh[2321]: Error: Can't open Display
```

This error has something to do with X11, that's what my Google searches tell me. 
So, my question is: How can I properly run a program like `xpdf` or libreoffice from Python?

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.call("/usr/bin/xpdf")
```

This is it, basically. I know that it has something to do with the graphical enviroment, but I don't know how I can solve it.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: What do you mean: " I plug in my USB device that start the Service"? Do you want to display xpdf to a monitor connected directly to your Pi or remotely?

Comment: The Goal is, that when I plug in an USB stick, the first pdf on it will be shown via xpdf or okular. Everything, from the udev-rules to the systemd-service is working fine, except that it won't start xpdf, okular, or any other graphical program.

Comment: Is the gnome media handling functionality not applicable? https://askubuntu.com/questions/642511/how-to-autorun-files-and-scripts-in-ubuntu-when-inserting-a-usb-stick-like-autor

Comment: That's another idea I had, but the best way would be that no Keyboard or mouse Need to be attached to the Pi. Just start it, plug in the USB and the PDF presentation starts.

Answer (score 1):

The X display system has very good security to stop random local processes from just displaying stuff to the local screen (It was more a problem in the old days of expensive Sun and SGI systems where computer labs would often let users telnet to other boxes. Much fun could be had!).

If the user running the xpdf is the same user as the one who's logged into the X session, then you simply need to tell xpdf where to connect it's UI to. This is usually done by exporting `DISPLAY=:0` to the environment, which means "connect to the first local screen". Most X programs also support `-display :0` argument.

So do:

```
/usr/bin/xpdf -display :0
```

or:

```
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xpdf
```

It's very unlikely that you have more than one X session so `:0` will work 99% of the time.

Comment: You could disable X authentication by calling `xhost +`, but use that as last resort and understand consequences.

Comment: True, but they still need to define where DISPLAY is.

Comment: But if the users are different then the old `xhost +localhost` will come in handy :) . It's nice to know this stuff is still relevant

Comment: You can find the display number and logged in user with `loginctl session-status`. The original issue is that the systemd-service doesn't run within that session.

Comment: I think you can use `xauth` to do better cross-account sharing but I'd have to acquaint myself with it

Comment: You can; it's basically `xauth -f $user1/.Xauthority merge $user2/.Xauthority`, though that's one of the crudest methods to go about it. `extract` to request a specific display key instead of absorbing all of them, and `generate` to make a new key (so you can revoke it, or run it untrusted).

Comment: I tried "export DISPLAY=:0" to /etc/Profile, didn't work. 
When I run "/usr/bin/xpdf --display :0" I get a wrong argument response.
"xhost +" didn't work too.
I still get the "Cant open Display"....

Comment: Check the man page; there's only one dash in `-display`, and system services don't run profile, that's for login shells.

Comment: My fault. I've updated the answer. Remember, you can also set an environment value on the same line as the command as demonstrated in the answer: `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xpdf`

Comment: If you need to run `xhost`, use `DISPLAY=:0 xhost +localhost`

Comment: In this instance I'm kind of wondering if this is a single purpose device, where you might want something like `xinit xpdf /media/*/*.pdf -- :1` to just start a separate session with that particular task.

Comment: Great idea! You should give that as answer, at least for someone else to use one day

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is that `xpdf` isn't finding a display to connect to, we have two basic options: find and authenticate with an existing display, or make a new one. The latter is usually easier, something like:

```
xinit /usr/bin/xpdf -fullscreen $PDFFILE -- :2
```

This would start a new X display :2 running only xpdf, not even a window manager.

Answer (score -2):

It finally worked, after trying and going crazy for around 2 weeks.
What worked was

```
os.system("DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xpdf)
```

I know that subprocess.call is the better way to call the program, but it doesn't seem to work right now.
I'll try the way that Yann suggested later on, but for now I'm just overwhelmed with joy that it just works.

Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The critical thing was the use of `DISPLAY` which I introduced you to in my answer. My answer gave an indepth description of what `DISPLAY` means and how to use it. Something you seem to neglect in your sudden brainwave answer. On Stackoverflow, the courteous thing to do is to upvote useful answers and accept answers which solved the problem you asked. In this case, that was my answer which ended your 2 week quest. Both Yann and I spent a good deal of time writing these answers. The fact that you used `os.system` is neither here nor there.

Comment: Probably missing `shell=True` for subprocess.call, otherwise you need to split the arguments yourself, including setting the environment variable (might be via os.environ or subprocess.Popen).